# Maven terms -- dependency and plugin, repository vs. pluginRepository

Tags: java, maven

I've been working with Maven for days but still get confused about some of the terms:

First question is what is the difference between `repository` and `pluginRepository`? If there is functional difference so shall I put one url for both?

Second question is what is the difference between `dependency` and `plugin`? Maybe they are totally different item to compare because `plugin` can include `dependencies`, but to me `plugins` look like some kind of dependencies in a build? Just like "This `build` depends on these plugins, and one of this plugin depends on that dependencies", I always think dependencies are kind of library jars, and plugins are library jars or depending projects in jars...

Sorry if the question is kind of dumb, but I am really confused. Please give a hint, thanks.

Comment: Have a read of: http://i-proving.com/2009/01/13/managing-your-plugins-as-distinct-from-pluginmanagement/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Back in Maven1.0, plugins and normal artifacts were in different repositories (as far as I know). In Maven2+ they are stored together in a repository. But there are many different repositories out there from many different companies and projects so you have to pick the repositories you need.

A plugin is a tool you use at the execution of your maven build. For example, the compiler plugin compiles your Java code into Bytecode.
A normal dependency are artifacts you use in your application like libraries.

Both plugins and artifacts can have transitive dependencies. That means they have dependencies themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback. So is there any functional difference between `pluginRepository` and `Repository`?

Comment: @Subarule Technical no. It's for having different configurations->behavior for plugins in contrary to normal artifacts. For example you want to use different update policy or you want no SNAPSHOT plugins.