# Difference between repository and pluginrepository

Tags: maven

My Android Maven project pom.xml contains the following entries. Now everything works fine. What is the difference between `<repositories>` entries and the `<pluginRepositories>` entries.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
                <url>http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <name>my-repo</name>
      <url>http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
             <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this online book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @otakun85 stated, There is no technical difference at all. It's for having different configurations->behavior for plugins in contrary to normal artifacts. See [repository vs. pluginRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045065/1626878) for more details.

Also check [maven-users mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200604.mbox/%3C443CA75A.4010309@web.de%3E), It provides quite good explanation to it.

Comment: A bit misleading to say "there is no technical difference." If you have your own package manager and you don't set pluginRepository, that is not going to fall back onto the "regular" repository.

Answer (score 15):

Maven will resolve plugin dependencies using the configured `pluginRepository`. Other artifact dependencies (eg. a parent pom) are resolved using `repository`.
Note: Things available on maven central will be resolved by default so you wouldn't normally need to include `repository` for those.

For example, if your pom.xml specifies a parent pom and a plugin dependency that both exist in the same repository you must still specify **both** `repository` AND `pluginRepository`. If you only configure one then maven will complain with "Unresolvable *X*" errors.