# Maven-tomcat plugin - cannot specify location of external jars

Tags: maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using the Maven-tomcat plugin. However for the war to start it needs certain jars. I have checked in these jars to our nexus server and added it to the maven tomcat plugin as dependencies - however, when I run mvn tomcat6:run, the build fails. The maven tomcat plugin is trying to find the dependent jars in the central repo and not in my nexus server. Is there some way to specify which repository it should look into?
Or is there some way to specify a folder to the maven - tomcat plugin which contains the necessary additional jars? I tried all the options like classesDir and additionalClasspathDirs but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I typically set up my companies nexus server as a repository in my global settings.xml thusly:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

 ...

 <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>repositories</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>my-nexus</id>
          <name>My Nexus</name>
      <url>http://my.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  ...

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>repositories</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Then it will be found by all my projects.  If you do not control your gloabl settings, user settings will do just fine as well.

**--------------- EDIT -----------------**

I just realized this is asking about dependencies for the tomcat *plugin*...  Plugins pull their dependencies from a different set of repositories specified by the `<pluginRepositories>` element.  So, you would need something like this:

```
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>my-nexus</id>
          <name>My Nexus</name>
          <url>http://my.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
```

I tried finding good documentation on this, but its kinda glossed over in the maven docs.  There is a similar question found here:

[Difference between repository and pluginrepository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14396017/516433)

Comment: I have already done this but it still doesn't work. The compile, deploy, etc to my Nexus repositories happens fine. Only problem is the tomcat plugin still continues to search for the dependent jars in the central repo.

Comment: @VandanaGopal, Are you sure your eclipse maven configuration is pointing to your settings.xml that contains that configuration? `Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations->Global settings from installation directory`

Comment: I have placed the eclipse maven configuration in my parent pom.xml itself which is inherited by all the child poms and  maven is definitely picking it up since the usual deployment of jars to my Nexus server works fine.

Comment: @VandanaGopal, Sorry, I misread your question...  What you are looking for is `<pluginRepositories>` not `<repositories>`.  The format is the same, but plugins find their dependencies from a separate set of repositories...  I will update my answer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had also already placed the pluginRepositories element in my parent pom.xml but it still doesn't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

As you add plugin dependencies (AFAIC).

You must add this new repo in pluginRepositories/pluginRepository section.

HTH