# New to Maven, seeing issue on build Malformed POM G:\WorkSpace\Test\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'pluginRepositories'

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and trying to set up my Workspace for the first time, Not seeing an error until build

Malformed POM G:\WorkSpace\Test\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'pluginRepositories'

```
<properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>7.0</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>7.0</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.release>7.0</maven.compiler.release>
            <java.version>12.0.2</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>bintray</id>
                <name>Groovy Bintray</name>
                <url>https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven</url>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version><!-- 3.6.2 is the minimum -->
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <indy /><!-- optional; supported by batch 2.4.12-04+ -->
                                <configScript>config.groovy</configScript><!-- optional; supported 
                                    by batch 2.4.13-02+ -->
                            </compilerArguments>
                            <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning><!-- optional; supported by batch 
                                2.5.8-02+ -->
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>3.5.0-01</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                                <version>2.5.8-02</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help offered would be great, if you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between repository and pluginrepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396017/difference-between-repository-and-pluginrepository)

Answer (score 0):

`pluginRepositories` element does not belong to `build` element. It should be under `<project>` element (same level as `<dependencies>`)

Answer (score 0):

The `<pluginRepositories>` section is not part of the build settings. It belongs to the environment settings.
Take a look at this: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview

In this case this is the right `pom.xml` structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


        <properties>
            <!-- properties -->
        </properties>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>bintray</id>
                <name>Groovy Bintray</name>
                <url>https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven</url>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version><!-- 3.6.2 is the minimum -->
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- plugin configuration -->
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- these dependencies are used by the plugin -->
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- plugins used by compiling, packaging or tests -->
        </dependencies>                
    </project>
```