# Build a Maven plugin: Can the build access pluginRepositories?

Tags: java, maven

In a usual Maven build, dependencies are resolved from the `<repositories>` in the settings.xml, while plugins used in the build are resolved from `<pluginRepositories>`.

When I *build a Maven plugin*, is this build able to resolve dependencies from a `<pluginRepository>` (specified in the settings.xml)? Or are pluginRepositories only for executing plugins?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396017/difference-between-repository-and-pluginrepository, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044909/maven-terms-dependency-and-plugin-repository-vs-pluginrepository/12045065#12045065 and http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200604.mbox/%3C443CA75A.4010309@web.de%3E

Comment: @lexicore Thank you, but actually I did not find a definitive answer to my question in the sources. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think Maven behaves differently if your project is a `maven-plugin` or a 'normal' one.

Comment: Neither did I, I've included links just as "recommended reading".